# Audio from usb bluetooth adapter (4.0) always breaking in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, bluetooth

Why is audio from usb bluetooth adapter always breaking in Ubuntu. Tried with 14.04, 18.04 and 20.04. Same every time. Works well with windows.I am able to transfer files. Problem is only with the audio.

Comment: Please provide more information about the issue. This is very vague and could be any number of things. What have you done to debug this yourself, have you tried other bluetooth devices. Have you installed all the relevant bluetooth apps, is there anything in the logs that might help and so on.

Comment: Bluetooth apps? If you were referring to drivers, the adapter is already being detected by the system. And i am able to transfer files both to and from the system. And yes i have tried with different Bluetooth adapters- one version 2 another version 4. The problem is with the audio, being fed to a Bluetooth headset, which keeps breaking continuously, be it media from the hard disk or streaming content. Initially i thought the problem was due to the older version of Bluetooth (v 2). So i bought a new dongle with version 4. The problem persists.........

Comment: ........I use different systems which have Ubuntu 14.04, 18.04 and 20.04 installed. There is this problem with all of them. These systems (which also has windows installed along with Ubuntu), audio is smooth without any breaking, in windows (8.1 and 10). Also tried turning off devices which might interfere with Bluetooth like cordless phone, and by switching to a wired connection. Still have the same problem.